# How can I get the argument spec on a decorated function?

Tags: python

I need to determine the argspec (inspect.getargspec) of a function within a decorator:

```
def decor(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def _decor(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return _decor

@decor
def my_func(key=1, value=False):
    pass
```

I need to be able to inspect the wrapped "my_func" and return the key/value arguments and their defaults. It seems that inspect.getargspec doesn't get the proper function.

(FWIW I need this for some runtime inspection/validation and later documentation generation)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use Michele Simionato's [decorator module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) to decorate your function,
its `decorator.decorator` will preserve the original function's signature.

```
import inspect
import decorator

@decorator.decorator
def decor(my_func,*args,**kw):
    result=my_func(*args,**kw)
    return result

@decor
def my_func(key=1, value=False):
    pass
decorated_argspec = inspect.getargspec(my_func)
print(decorated_argspec)
# ArgSpec(args=['key', 'value'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(1, False))
```

Comment: Why in the result keywords=None?

Comment: The names are a bit confusing. `keywords` is set to the name of the `**` argument. For example, if `def bar(**kw): pass`, then `inspect.getargspec(bar)` would return `ArgSpec(args=[], varargs=None, keywords='kw', defaults=None)`.

Answer (score 5):

I've written a simple class that does what you want. This will achieve the same thing that `functools.wraps` does as well as preserve the function's signature (from `getargspec`'s point of view). Read the docstring for this class on [my gist for more information](https://gist.github.com/frenchtoast747/532e2de07adb4bada890).

**Note:** this only works on decorating functions and not on class methods.

```
import types

class decorator(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == '__class__':
            # calling type(decorator()) will return <type 'function'>
            # this is used to trick the inspect module >:)
            return types.FunctionType
        return super(decorator, self).__getattribute__(name)

    def __init__(self, fn):
        # let's pretend for just a second that this class
        # is actually a function. Explicity copying the attributes
        # allows for stacked decorators.
        self.__call__ = fn.__call__
        self.__closure__ = fn.__closure__
        self.__code__ = fn.__code__
        self.__doc__ = fn.__doc__
        self.__name__ = fn.__name__
        self.__defaults__ = fn.__defaults__
        self.func_defaults = fn.func_defaults
        self.func_closure = fn.func_closure
        self.func_code = fn.func_code
        self.func_dict = fn.func_dict
        self.func_doc = fn.func_doc
        self.func_globals = fn.func_globals
        self.func_name = fn.func_name
        # any attributes that need to be added should be added
        # *after* converting the class to a function
        self.args = None
        self.kwargs = None
        self.result = None
        self.function = fn

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

        self.before_call()
        self.result = self.function(*args, **kwargs)
        self.after_call()

        return self.result

    def before_call(self):
        pass

    def after_call(self):
        pass
```

#### Simply create a new decorator by subclassing

```
import time

class timeit(decorator):
    def before_call(self):
        self.start = time.time()
    def after_call(self):
        end = time.time()
        print "Function {0} took {1} seconds to complete.".format(
            self.__name__, end - self.start
        )

@timeit
def my_really_cool_function(a, b, c, d='asdf', q='werty'):
    time.sleep(5)
```

#### Use it like any normal decorated function

```
args = inspect.getargspec(my_really_cool_function)
print args

my_really_cool_function(1,2,3,4,5)
```

#### Output

```
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'q'], varargs=None,
        keywords=None, defaults=('asdf', 'werty'))
Function my_really_cool_function took 5.0 seconds to complete.
```