# How to get through decorator to get the underlying function arguments information?

Tags: python, arguments, decorator

I write `get_function_arg_data(func)` as below code to get the function `func`'s arguments information:

```
def get_function_arg_data(func):
    import inspect
    func_data = inspect.getargspec(func)
    args_name = func_data.args #func argument list
    args_default = func_data.defaults #funcargument default data list
    return args_name, args_default


def showduration(user_function):
    ''' show time duration decorator'''
    import time
    def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.clock()
        result = user_function(*args, **kwargs)
        print "%s()_Time: %0.5f"%(user_function.__name__, time.clock()-t1)
        return result
    return wrapped_f


def foo(para1, para2=5, para3=7):
    for i in range(1000):
        s = para1+para2+para3
    return s

@showduration
def bar(para1, para2, para3):
    for i in range(1000):
        s=para1+para2+para3
    return s

print get_function_arg_data(foo)
bar(1,2,3)
print get_function_arg_data(bar)


>>> 
(['para1', 'para2', 'para3'], (5, 7))
bar()_Time: 0.00012
([], None)
>>>
```

`get_function_arg_data()` works for `foo`, not for `bar` for bar is decorated by a decorator `@showduration` . My question is how to penetrate the decorator to get the underlying function's information (argument list and default value) ?

Thanks for your tips.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the argument spec on a decorated function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972290/how-can-i-get-the-argument-spec-on-a-decorated-function)

Comment: I add @decorator.decorator before "def showduration(user_function):", and python pop TypeError: showduration() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is, or at least know of, any general way to "penetrate" a decorated function and get at the underlying function's information because Python's concept of function decoration is *so* general -- if fact, generally speaking, there's nothing that requires or guarantees that the original function will be called at all (although that's usually the case).

Therefore, a more practical question would be: *How could I write my own decorators which would allow me to inspect the underlying function's argument information?*

One easy way, previously suggested, would be to use Michele Simionato's [decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) module (and write decorators compatible with it).

A less robust, but extremely simple way of doing this would be to do what is shown below based on the code in your question:

```
def get_function_arg_data(func):
    import inspect
    func = getattr(func, '_original_f', func) # use saved original if decorated
    func_data = inspect.getargspec(func)
    args_name = func_data.args #func argument list
    args_default = func_data.defaults #funcargument default data list
    return args_name, args_default

def showduration(user_function):
    '''show time duration decorator'''
    import time
    def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.clock()
        result = user_function(*args, **kwargs)
        print "%s()_Time: %0.5f"%(user_function.__name__, time.clock()-t1)
        return result
    wrapped_f._original_f = user_function  # save original function
    return wrapped_f

def foo(para1, para2=5, para3=7):
    for i in range(1000):
        s = para1+para2+para3
    return s

@showduration
def bar(para1, para2, para3):
    for i in range(1000):
        s=para1+para2+para3
    return s

print 'get_function_arg_data(foo):', get_function_arg_data(foo)
print 'get_function_arg_data(bar):', get_function_arg_data(bar)
```

All the modification involves is saving the original function in an attribute named `_original_f` which is added the wrapped function returned by the decorator. The `get_function_arg_data()` function then simply checks for this attribute and returns information based its value rather the decorated function passed to it.

While this approach doesn't work with just *any* decorated function, only ones which have had the special attribute added to them, it is compatible with both Python 2 & 3.

Output produced by the code shown:

```
get_function_arg_data(foo): (['para1', 'para2', 'para3'], (5, 7))
get_function_arg_data(bar): (['para1', 'para2', 'para3'], None)
```

Comment: Nice tip. I learn the way from your solution on how to pass the information from underlying function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've installed Michele Simionato's [decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) module, you can make your`showduration`decorator work with it by making some minor modifications to it and to the nested`wrapped_f()`function defined in it so the latter fits the signature that module's `decorator.decorator()` function expects:

```
import decorator

def showduration(user_function):
    ''' show time duration decorator'''
    import time
    def wrapped_f(user_function, *args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.clock()
        result = user_function(*args, **kwargs)
        print "%s()_Time: %0.5f"%(user_function.__name__, time.clock()-t1)
        return result
    return decorator.decorator(wrapped_f, user_function)
```

However, the module really shines because it will let you reduce boilerplate stuff like the above down to just:

```
import decorator

@decorator.decorator
def showduration(user_function, *args, **kwargs):
    import time
    t1 = time.clock()
    result = user_function(*args, **kwargs)
    print "%s()_Time: %0.5f"%(user_function.__name__, time.clock()-t1)
    return result
```

With either set of the above changes, your sample code would output:

```
(['para1', 'para2', 'para3'], (5, 7))
bar()_Time: 0.00026                  
(['para1', 'para2', 'para3'], None)
```

Comment: Thank you for offering the detail solution on how to use the  decorator.decorator() , It is very helpful. I accept @martineau's answer for I prefer the solution with less dependent on 3rd package. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: P.S. BTW, you shouldn't be overly concerned about using Michele Simionato's [decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) module. It's pure Python, easy to install, well documented, looks to be very robust, and works with both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Sorry for my careless of not able to recongnize both names are same.  :-)