# How do you implement __str__ for a function?

Tags: python, function

Given a function `foo`:

```
def foo(x):
     pass
```

Printing its representation by invoking `str` or `repr` gives you something boring like this:

```
str(foo)
'<function foo at 0x119e0c8c8>'
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to override a function's `__str__` method to print something else. Essentially, I'd like to do:

```
str(foo)
"I'm foo!'
```

Now, I understand that the description of a function should come from `__doc__` which is the function's docstring. However, this is merely an experiment.

In attempting to figure out a solution to this problem, I came across implementing `__str__` for *`classes`*: [How to define a __str__ method for a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144026/how-to-define-a-str-method-for-a-class)

This approach involved defining a metaclass with an `__str__` method, and then attempting to assign the `__metaclass__` hook in the actual class.

I wondered whether the same could be done to the class `function`, so here's what I tried -

```
In [355]: foo.__class__
Out[355]: function

In [356]: class fancyfunction(type):
     ...:     def __str__(self):
     ...:         return self.__name__
     ...:     

In [357]: foo.__class__.__metaclass__ = fancyfunction
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
```

I figured it wouldn't work, but it was worth a shot!

So, what's the best way to implement `__str__` for a function?

Comment: Which methods/functions are called during `str(foo)`? Shouldn't it be `foo.__str__()`? Why can't we simply do `foo.__str__ = lambda : "I'm a foo!"`?

Comment: @EricDuminil `__str__` for functions is not writable.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: Python doesn't complain during `foo.__str__ = lambda : "I'm a foo!"` should the syntax be different because it's a private method? Is the assignment simply ignored?

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes, it won't complain because arbitrary attributes can be bound to function instances. In fact, you can do `f.__str__ = lambda: 6` and `foo.__str__()` returns `6`; the string return value is not enforced. `__str__` is called for functions using hooks via `type(foo)`, and not via the instance `foo`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A function in Python is just a callable object. Using `def` to define function is *one* way to create such an object. But there is actually nothing stopping you from creating a callable type and creating an instance of it to get a function.

So the following two things are basically equal:

```
def foo ():
    print('hello world')


class FooFunction:
    def __call__ (self):
        print('hello world')

foo = FooFunction()
```

Except that the last one obviously allows us to set the function type’s special methods, like `__str__` and `__repr__`.

```
class FooFunction:
    def __call__ (self):
        print('hello world')

    def __str__ (self):
        return 'Foo function'

foo = FooFunction()
print(foo) # Foo function
```

But creating a type just for this becomes a bit tedious and it also makes it more difficult to understand what the function does: After all, the `def` syntax allows us to *just* define the function body. So we want to keep it that way!

Luckily, Python has this great feature called decorators which we can use here. We can create a function decorator that will wrap any function inside a custom type which calls a custom function for the `__str__`. That could look like this:

```
def with_str (str_func):
    def wrapper (f):
        class FuncType:
            def __call__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
                # call the original function
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            def __str__ (self):
                # call the custom __str__ function
                return str_func()

        # decorate with functool.wraps to make the resulting function appear like f
        return functools.wraps(f)(FuncType())
    return wrapper
```

We can then use that to add a `__str__` function to any function by simply decorating it. That would look like this:

```
def foo_str ():
    return 'This is the __str__ for the foo function'

@with_str(foo_str)
def foo ():
    print('hello world')
```

```
>>> str(foo)
'This is the __str__ for the foo function'
>>> foo()
hello world
```

Obviously, doing this has some limitations and drawbacks since you cannot *exactly* reproduce what `def` would do for a new function inside that decorator.

For example, using the `inspect` module to look at the arguments will not work properly: For the callable type, it will include the `self` argument and when using the generic decorator, it will only be able to report the details of `wrapper`. However, there might be *some* solutions, for example discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972290/how-can-i-get-the-argument-spec-on-a-decorated-function), that will allow you to restore *some* of the functionality.

But that usually means you are investing a lot of effort just to get a `__str__` work on a function object which will probably very rarely be used. So you should think about whether you actually need a `__str__` implementation for your functions, and what kind of operations you will do on those functions then.

Comment: Of course, just about everything besides function call functionality will break when you do this. Some of it can be handled manually, like the descriptor protocol. Some of it can sort of be handled, like signature introspection. Some of it is never going to work.

Comment: @PM2Ring Changed the answer to wrap the final function with `functools.wrapped` so that the essentials are restored :)

Comment: You can remove the need for the `self` argument by making `__call__` a static method (`@staticmethod def __call__(no, self, arg):`). Use `functools.wraps` to restore some function attributes (like the name and annotations). Otherwise, very good answer!

Comment: @KenHilton `@staticmethod` does the same as ignoring the passing `self` argument (Python will still pass `self` to the function; it’s just that the decorator will skip it for you). There is no real benefit here in wrapping the function *again*. There are already enough levels of wrapping involved here. Also, `__call__` is still an instance method, so even though I don’t need `self` here, making it a static method would feel wrong. – As for `wraps`, I am using that.

Answer (score 12):

If you find yourself wrapping functions, it's useful to look at `functools.partial`.  It's primarily for binding arguments of course, but that's optional.  It's also a class that wraps functions, removing the boilerplate of doing so from scratch.

```
from functools import partial

class foo(partial):
    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm foo!"

@foo
def foo():
    pass

assert foo() is None
assert str(foo) == "I'm foo!"
```