# Why does print expect __str__ to return str?

Tags: python, json

Print has no problem printing a dict:

```
d = dict()
d['x'] = 'y'
print(d)
```

> `{'x': 'y'}`

Then why does this fail?

```
class Utterance:
    def __init__(self, intent_name, text):
        self.intent_name = intent_name
        self.text = text

    def __str__(self):
        return dict(self.__dict__)

print(utterance)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     print(utterance) TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type dict)
> ```

(I know it is standard for `__str__` to return string, but I have a reason related to JSON encoding to return dict)

Comment: Have you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452513/how-do-you-implement-str-for-a-function?

Comment: The entire **object model** expects `__str__` to well - return a string... even `dict`s `__str__` uses its data to build a string to return... you could do `return str(dict(self.__dict__))`... (or make a custom method to return a dict, and then have your `__str__` method return the `str` of that)

Comment: Why not use JSON representation? `return json.dumps(self.__dict__)`

Comment: `__str__` expects a `str` to be returned.

Comment: @lonut Ticus using __dict__ method still doesnt solve my problem. What I need is this (class of dicts)
[{'intent_name': 'i1', 'text': 'u1'}, {'intent_name': 'i1', 'text': 'u2'}]    <class 'list'>
{'intent_name': 'i1', 'text': 'u1'}                                           <class 'dict'>

json.dumps(self.__dict__) returns string which is not right here

Comment: @gammay what problem do you try to solve? what is your expected result?

Comment: If you don't want `str`, create another function `my_repr` which can return whatever you need and call `print(utterance.my_repr())`

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__):

> **object.__str__(self)**
>   Called by str(object) and the built-in functions format() and print() to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of an object. The return value **must** be a string object.

**tl;dr**
Why does print expect **str** to return str?

Because language spec says so.

Answer (score 0):

`object.__str__` is meant to return a human readable string representation of your object, in your case, this method returns a `dict`, you may use:

```
class Utterance:
    def __init__(self, intent_name, text):
        self.intent_name = intent_name
        self.text = text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__dict__.__str__()

print(Utterance(1, 'my_text'))
```

output:

```
{'intent_name': 1, 'text': 'my_text'}
```